# What is proc file system? Why is its size zero?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am confused with word **virtual** in Linux. My tutor told me that `/proc` is a virtual file system.
If that means it's not real, then why is it implemented?
How is it implemented?
If I am doing `cat` on `/proc` then I am getting so much data, but when I am doing `ls -l /proc` it is showing size of **zero**.

Comment: It exports data from kernel. Virtual = no real storage

Comment: @AlexHoppus No real storage means what ? There are so many directories inside /proc then How size is zero.

Comment: hi raja, have you done any programming?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/619955/how-does-proc-work

Comment: @AhmedMasud Yes

Comment: thanks @sawdust and achal for your  reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's a memory file system. it's a window to the kernel that means using `/proc` you can see what's happening inside the kernel.
`/proc` contains `virtual` files which reveals the `current state` of the running kernel.

for e.g when you are doing

```
root@BC:/home/abc# ls -l /proc/modules 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 11 22:00 /proc/modules
```

but when you are doing `cat /proc/modules` it's showing so much of data, why because files inside `/proc` are `logical or virtual` that **on demand** contents of files will be generated.

`/proc` is implemented for specially `Reading` purpose( to view/see whats happening inside the kernel) not `writing` purpose. We can write into 
`/proc` but that's discouraged.

You can see more here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

I hope it help's.

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by on demand, If I will not perform cat /proc/modules then where it will be stored ?

Comment: @raja in the data structures over the kernel.